# Laravel SQL select and update model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I try select from database and update values with model, but get error:

```
Call to undefined method stdClass::save()
```

My code:

```
$user = db::table('users')->where('name', 'John')->where('age', 30)->first();
if($user) {
    $user->name = 'Tom';
    $user->age = 31;
    $user->save();
}
```

i get this error:

Comment: i think `db` should be `DB`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use `save()` you have to build the query using an actual model. Currently you're just selecting something from the db without hydrating a model.

```
$user = User::where('name', 'John')->where('age', 30)->first();
if($user) {
    $user->name = 'Tom';
    $user->age = 31;
    $user->save();
}
```